# SQL Server BCP Utility incorrect data import

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am using [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to import a `.csv` file. One of the columns has a value separated by comma but its enclosed in doubled quotes. BCP tools is unable to detect it and is incorrectly uploading data to my table.

Here is a repro:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_temptable]
(
    --[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Column2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Column3] [varchar](100) NULL,

    /*PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
*/
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Test data in `inputData.csv` file:

```
value1,"test,test",value3
```

When I run the bcp command it works

```
bcp "testDB.dbo.test_temptable" in  c:\temp\test\inputData.csv -c -t,  -T -S "testDBServer" -e c:\temp\test\error.csv

1 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1      Average : (1000.00 rows per sec.)
```

However data in table is incorrect:

[image]

Column2 should have been **test, test** and column 3 **value3**.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short.. it won't work with commas in your data and as a delimiter.  Even though Excel handles it, SQL BCP isn't as friendly:

[sql server Bulk insert csv with data having comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226107/sql-server-bulk-insert-csv-with-data-having-comma)

I've had to do this in the past and you have some options:

- Open up the `.csv` file in Excel, save it as a tab delimited file (which makes it a `.txt`), then you can run this to indicate you now are using a `tab` as the delimiter:

  `bcp "testDB.dbo.test_temptable" in  c:\temp\test\inputData.csv -c -t"\t" -T -S "testDBServer" -e c:\temp\test\error.csv`

  Of course if you have a tab in your data.. same problem.  However using the little example you have provided that *does* work.
- You could try using `BULK INSERT` from inside SQL
- You could look into using `SSIS` or `DTX` but honestly I try to stay away from that extra overhead/complexity.

Comment: Thanks @sniperd. My DBA is not allowing us to use BULK INSERT. I will explore using tab as delimiter