# how to specify text qualified comma delimiter in BULK INSERT Format File for columns which may have null values

Tags: sql-server

See this small sample of my CSV file:

```
"ID","TRANSACTION_TIME","CONTAINER_NUMBER","EVENT"
33115541,"2019-04-03 00:47:41.000000","MSKU1128096",
33115538,"2019-04-03 01:34:49.000000","MSKU1128096","Gate Out"
33115545,"2019-04-03 00:47:55.000000","MSKU4717839",
```

This is the format file I created

```
14.0
4
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 ",\""     2 ID                  ""
2 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\",\""   3 TRANSACTION_TIME    ""
3 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\",\""   4 CONTAINER_NUMBER    ""
4 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\"\r\n"  5 EVENT               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The issue is that the 4th column may have null values as you can see from rows 1 and 3 (excluding header)

See below my BULK INSERT command

```
bulk insert dbo.DRISPIN_CONTAINER_HISTORY_STG1
from 'e:\dri_container_history_initial.csv'
with (
    firstrow = 2,
    formatfile = 'e:\container_history_initial.fmt'
)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 305
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I have also tried specifying a Prefix Length of 2, but get some different errors.

I know I can possibly take the the values in with the qualifiers into staging table and then strip them out. But ideally I would like to see if there is a way to do this with BULK INSERT or BCP

Thanks in advance

Comment: All of your `SQLCHAR`s are defined as a length of `0`, if I'm reading that correctly.  Also, why are you important columns like `TRANSACTION_TIME` and `ID` as a string when they clearly a `datetime2(6)`, `int` respectively?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? `14.0` is SQL Server 2017 which [has full CSV support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#e-importing-data-from-a-csv-file). You don't need a format file in this case. A simple `WITH ( FORMAT='CSV')` will probably work as `"` is the default `FIELDQUOTE` value

Comment: My development server is 2017, however I need the solution to be compatible with older versions for production. Is there a solution for version 11 and 12 ?

Answer (score 1):

Full CSV support was addedin SQL Server 2017. I suspect that's the version used here since the file's format version number is 14.0.

The following command will load the file using a double quote as the `FIELDQUOTE` character and `CRLF` as the row terminator :

```
create table testtable 
(
    "ID" bigint,
    "TRANSACTION_TIME" datetime2(0),
    "CONTAINER_NUMBER" varchar(200),
    "EVENT" varchar(200)
)


bulk insert dbo.testtable
from 'c:\path\to\testcsv.csv'
with ( 
    format='csv',
     FIRSTROW=2
)


select * from testtable
```

The results are :

```
ID          TRANSACTION_TIME    CONTAINER_NUMBER    EVENT
33115541    2019-04-03 00:47:41 MSKU1128096         NULL
33115538    2019-04-03 01:34:49 MSKU1128096         Gate Out
33115545    2019-04-03 00:47:55 MSKU4717839         NULL
```

`FORMAT = 'CSV'` still can't handle a missing newline at the end of the file

Comment: My development server is 2017, however I need the solution to be compatible with older versions for production. Is there a solution for version 11 and 12 ?

Comment: No, CSV format was added in 2017. Why don't you use SSIS instead? For ad-hoc use, the latest versions of SSMS have a wizard that can handle many weird flat file formats in the database context menu, `Tasks > Import Flat File...`. That's an SSMS tool though, it can't be stored and executed the way an SSIS package can

Comment: @rarpal previous version just don't understand field/text qualifiers, so they can't handle optional fields with quotes. SSIS *does* support text qualifiers.