# When exporting SSMS query result, replace every space character encountered to a comma?

Tags: sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

I am exporting a big SSMS query result (2M lines, 1 column) to a CSV file.

Each row may contain multiple words.

Is it possible to tokenize each line, such that every "space" character encountered will be comma-delimited?

For example (column header not included)

Database column:

```
The quick brown fox  
Jumps over the lazy dog
```

Query result in CSV file:

```
The,quick,brown,fox  
Jumps,over,the,lazy,dog
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226107/sql-server-bulk-insert-csv-with-data-having-comma

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing that in the query itself rather than using SSMS - just use a replace function:

```
SELECT REPLACE([MyCol], ' ', ',');
```

Then in SSMS export options turn text-qualifiers off.

I'm sure you're aware but and it's your intention but this will destroy your nice tabular data into a ragged edge!